# How to use AWS memcached with multiple nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I am new to AWS, and I want to store some temporary data on memcached. My memcached has two nodes, one in us-east-1-a, one in us-east-1-b. It stores data in 2 nodes but is not syncing them. Is there any way I can get all data from 2 buckets instead of going into 2 nodes 1 by 1.

edit: I use telnet to connect to the endpoint of memcached

Answer (score 2):

So memcached clusters do not replicate data between nodes. Only redis will do that if setup like that, that is why you need to use the **Configuration Endpoint** for memcached, it knows all the instances in your cluster

> The Memcached engine supports **partitioning** your data across multiple nodes
>
> A Memcached cluster is a logical grouping of one or more ElastiCache Nodes. **Data is partitioned across the nodes in a Memcached cluster.**
>
> Memcached cluster, If you use Automatic Discovery, you can use the cluster's configuration endpoint to configure your Memcached client. This means you must use a client that supports Automatic Discovery.
>   If you don't use Automatic Discovery, you must configure your client to use the individual node endpoints for reads and writes. You must also keep track of them as you add and remove nodes.

[Finding the Endpoints for a Memcached Cluster (Console)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Endpoints.html)

Comment: Does this mean, if you don't use the Auto Discovery / ElastiCache Memcached Cluster Client, you need to restart your applications to use the new nodes?